# Rails/Ruby Radio Button Default Checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, radio-button, haml

I have:

```
- [ 'here now', 'trip scheduled', 'planning a trip', 'already visited' ].each do |travel|
  %div.field.radio.small.snug.bind                  
    = f.radio_button :expected_travel, travel
    = label_tag "visitors_guide_request_expected_travel[#{travel}]", travel.titleize
```

I need to have the radio button generated for 'here now' to be checked by default. What's the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass in the `:checked` option to your radio_button:

```
= f.radio_button :expected_travel, travel, :checked => travel == 'here now'
```

That will check the button whose value is `here now`

Comment: Rails is throwing a syntax error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'

Comment: I'm using ruby1.9+ hash syntax, maybe you're on an older ruby. Change the checked part to this: :checked => travel == 'here now'. I edited the answer with this.

Comment: That worked! This site is a mess. I took over for someone else and it has not been maintained well at all. Thanks!